# How to use linkbuttons within yui datatable?

Tags: yui-datatable, formatter

I use yui datatable and i have a field which is `resumePath` which is path to a file in a folder in my application... So how to use linkbutton and show my path on it...

`{ key: "resumepath", label: "Resumepath", width: 250, formatter: YAHOO.widget.DataTable.formatLink }`

and this doesnt work any suggestion... I want to make this file to downloaded when the user clicks on it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching i found the answer it should be like this

```
{ key: "resumepath", label: "Resumepath", width: 250, formatter: "link" }
```